# Error using acs.R: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?

Tags: r, recursion

I'm using the `acs` package in R. I'm passing a list of Census tracts as my geography, and then trying to fetch data from a particular ACS table for those Census tracts. But I'm getting the following errors:

`Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
Error during wrapup: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?`

I searched other Stack Overflow answers, and it seems like the key is to set the `Expressions` option to a higher number. But I tried adding `expressions = 100000` to my `acs.fetch` query and it still showed the same error.

Here's my code:

```
tracts <- format(na.omit(df$CensusTract), width = 5, nsmall = 2, decimal.mark ="", na.encode = FALSE, trim = TRUE)
mygeo <- geo.make(state=17,county=31,tract=c(tracts))
race <- acs.fetch(endyear=2014, span=5, geography = mygeo, table.number="B03002", dataset = "acs", col.names="pretty", expressions = 100000)
```

What's happening here and how do I fix it?